# MVC3 Razor view not rendering dynamically added controls on postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I  have to upload selected files and display these files as links on post back. 
In my view I am adding each of the uploaded files as links using

```
  @if (Model.IncidentLogInfoDetails.AttachmentCollection.AttachmentItemCollection.Any())
  {
      foreach (EML.Container.Attachment attachmentItem in Model.IncidentLogInfoDetails.AttachmentCollection.AttachmentItemCollection)
      {
           @Html.ActionLink(attachmentItem.FileName, "testing")
      }
  }
```

**this is my controller action:**

```
 public ActionResult UploadingFiles(HttpPostedFileBase imageFile)
    {
        // Converting to Attachment object
        Attachment fileAttachment = new Attachment();
        fileAttachment.FileName = "imageFile.FileName";
        fileAttachment.ContentType = imageFile.ContentType;
        fileAttachment.SizeInBytes = imageFile.ContentLength;

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            imageFile.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
            fileAttachment.BinaryData = ms.GetBuffer();
        }

        IncidentDetails incidentDetails = new IncidentDetails();
        incidentDetails.IncidentLogInfoDetails = new IncidentLogInfo();
        incidentDetails.IncidentLogInfoDetails.AttachmentCollection.AttachmentItemCollection = new List<Attachment>();

        incidentDetails.IncidentLogInfoDetails.AttachmentCollection.AttachmentItemCollection.Add(fileAttachment);
        return View("FileUploadingTest", incidentDetails);
    }
```

My problem is that even though the loop is getting executed and Action links are created ( on debugging), they are not displayed after post back. 
What am I missing ?

Comment: MVC doesn't have "postback" - that's a WebForms concept that leverages ViewState.

Comment: Then how can I display what files are uploaded by user

Comment: When you said "Action links are created" do you mean to say that you have anchor tags (`<a>`) created on your view?

Comment: I put a break point iside for each loop and if I am having 3 files uploaded, loop will get executed for 3 times creating '@Html.ActionLink(attachmentItem.FileName, "testing")'.
 But none of the links are displayed on the view .

Comment: Can you try creating the anchor tag without using the htmlhelper: `<a href="#">@attachmentItem.FileName</a>`? That's a bare minimum, it will help in your debugging.

Comment: Again same result. Even though it is going to loop and creating control, link is not getting displayed. It is coming if I refresh the page with F5. Is there any option to render html of the page forcefully from controller. Thanks

Comment: You can use ajax to create the links in document.ready

Comment: I tried ajax, but I am no able to get my seleced file 'HttpPostedFileBase imageFile' while using ajax. Can anyone please help me with how to upload file using ajax in mvc3 ...

Comment: At last I got the problem. I was rendering the page inside an iFrame on postback and the new page wih added links was getting rendered inside teh iFrame which was hidden :). Thanks everyone for trying to help.